# how to get the desired output in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

**Table Structure**

```
EID    COLA    COLB
1    name    A
1    age    23
1    city    hyd
1    email    abc@live.in
1    mobile    45126
2    name    B
2    age    43
2    city    bang
3    name    C
3    age    13
3    city    bang
3    email    jdf@live.in
```

I would like to have the output as below

```
 ID||COLA||COLB
    1||name||A
    1||age||23
    1||city||hyd
    1||email||abc@live.in
    1||mobile||45126
    2||name||B
    2||age||43
    2||city||bang
    2||email||NULL
    2||mobile||NULL
    3||name||C
    3||age||13
    3||city||bang
    3||email||jdf@live.in
    3||mobile||NULL
```

Can you kindly let me know how to achieve this output.
how to display the result where any of the mandatory fields (name,age,city,email,mobile)are missing then it should display as that field as Null, in the query we would provide in the where clause by filtering a single id value and cola as (name,age,city,email,mobile)

**my Query:**

```
select

case colA

when cola then colA+'||'+colB

end

from tbl

where cola in ('name','age','city','email','mobile')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that what you are asking would have been really easy if your table structure had required columns like `name`, `age`, `city` etc. Name Value Pair is not a good design for such tables, not to mention serious performance issues which will plague any solution against this structure.

Having said that, you can use either `PIVOT` / `UNPIVOT` or an Attribute table (a table containing list of attribute required) and `GROUP BY` with `CROSS JOIN`.

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE(
EID INT,   COLA VARCHAR(30),   COLB VARCHAR(30) )

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
(1,'name','A'),
(1,'age','23'),
(1,'city','hyd'),
(1,'email','abc@live.in'),
(1,'mobile','45126'),
(2,'name','B'),
(2,'age','43'),
(2,'city','bang'),
(3,'name','C'),
(3,'age','13'),
(3,'city','bang'),
(3,'email','jdf@live.in');
```

**Query using `PIVOT / UNPIVOT`**

```
SELECT EID, COLA,NULLIF(COLB,'') COLB
FROM 
(
SELECT EID,ISNULL([name],'') name,ISNULL([age],'') [age],ISNULL([city],'') [city],ISNULL([email],'') [email],ISNULL([mobile],'') [mobile]
FROM (SELECT EID,COLA,COLB
FROM @table1) T
PIVOT ( MAX(COLB) FOR COLA IN ( [name],[age],[city],[email],[mobile] ) ) AS pvt
) tbl
UNPIVOT (COLB FOR ColA IN (name,age,city,email,mobile)) AS Upvt
```

Notice that I am using `ISNULL(col,'')` because `UNPIVOT` excludes `NULL` values. If `''` is a valid value for you, you can use another string to denote  `NULL` or use the `GROUP BY` solution.

**Query using Attribute table and `GROUP BY` with `CROSS JOIN`**

```
;WITH Cols(Name) AS 
(
SELECT 'name' UNION ALL SELECT 'age'  UNION ALL SELECT 'city'  UNION ALL SELECT 'email'  UNION ALL SELECT 'mobile'
)

SELECT t.EID,C.Name,t1.COLB
FROM
(
SELECT EID
FROM @table1
GROUP BY EID
) t
CROSS JOIN Cols c
LEFT JOIN @table1 t1 ON t1.EID = t.EID and t1.COLA = C.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE DesireOutput(EID nvarchar(10),COLA NVARCHAR(10),COLB nvarchar(50))
```

> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('1','name','A' )
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('1','age','23')
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('1','city','hyd')
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('1','email','abc@live.IN')
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('1','mobile','45126')
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('2','name','B')
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('2','age','43')
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('2','city','bang')
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('3','name','C')
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('3','age','13')
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('3','city','bang')
>
> INSERT INTO DesireOutput VALUES ('3','email','jdf@live.IN')

```
 DECLARE @t AS TABLE ( ColA NVARCHAR(50) )

 INSERT  INTO @t
         SELECT DISTINCT
                 D.COLA
         FROM    DesireOutput D



 SELECT  t.EID ,         c.ColA ,         t1.COLB FROM    ( SELECT   
 EID           FROM      DesireOutput           GROUP BY  EID
         ) t
         CROSS JOIN @t c
         LEFT JOIN DesireOutput t1 ON t1.EID = t.EID
                                      AND t1.COLA = c.ColA ORDER BY EID
```